# How to build query with "sourcedoc" which is present in "SharePoint file" shared URL. I want to search file in OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using below URL to search files in Onedrive. How to add the query string as "Sourcecode"?

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query

Request parameters:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                // "queryString": "Presentation.pptx"
                //"queryString": "contoso filetype:pdf OR filetype:docx"
                //"queryString": "contoso 
                 path:\"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Team Site/Documents/\\""                              
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: string as "Sourcecode"? In the title you have "sourcedoc". The question is unclear.

Comment: for [file query api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#function-parameters), `The query text used to search for items. Values may be matched across several fields including filename, metadata, and file content.` query string can be appended in the url, or use it in graph SDK

Answer (score 0):

The `sourcedoc` value should be the same as `id` of the `listItem` which represents an item in a SharePoint list.

Try to specify the `sourcedoc` value in `queryString`.

Example:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "C2CB147F-1B73-4307-990E-37F7CBE090C6"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It will search across the metadata including id.